# How to terminate desktop and all programs within it created via CreateDesktop()?

Tags: c++, winapi

Basically, I was expecting `CloseDesktop()` would do something like this, but looks like it only closes the handle to the desktop (it returns 1, however) and I can always get a new handle to the desktop by its name via `OpenDesktop()`.

Is there any way to kill everything created in this desktop and the desktop itself?

Comment: Kernal handles are reference counted so if any other application has an open Desktop handle you will not close the Desktop.

Comment: ...and the active desktop probably always has an extra reference active.

Answer (score 0):

Windows are tied to the desktop they are created on so you can use [`EnumDesktopWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows) to enumerate and close/kill the windows/processes on a specific desktop. Killing the process might be a bit extreme since it can have windows (belonging to other threads) on a different desktop.